# Hölder's inequality. Understanding proof?!

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, convolution

I know how most standard textbooks show that $||f*g||_r \le ||f||_p||g||_q$ with $\frac{1}{r}+1=\frac{1}{p}+ \frac{1}{q}$, but I found a book where the hint $|f(x-y)g(y)|\le (|f(x-y)|^p|g(y)|^q)^{\frac{1}{r}}|f(x-y)|^{1-\frac{p}{r}}|g(y)|^{1-\frac{q}{r}}$ is given and it is said that one just needs to apply Hölder's inequality. But honestly, I don't see it how this follows. To which coefficients is Hölder's inequality applied here? Just in order to clarify this. It is clear how this expansion happened. All I am asking is how you get from the 2nd line to the first one by applying Hölder's inequality?

Comment: I know you're not asking this, but there is a nice and short proof of this with the help of Riesz-Thorin interpolation theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I misunderstood your question first. However, your proof is given [here](http://people.oregonstate.edu/~peterseb/mth627/docs/627w2004-convolution.pdf):

Comment: To which terms exactly? and what are the coefficients that sum inversely up to 1?

Comment: To the funxtions $h(y)$ and $g(y)$.

Comment: but what would this expansion be good for then?

Comment: @Lipschitz: Ah I see your point now. Let me edit my answer to include it.

Comment: @Lipschitz: This is an equality as you have written it. I guess the book wants to apply the inequality after this step.

Comment: sorry, this is not useful. it is clear how this expansion happened. what i am asking for is: how do they apply Hölder's inequality to this expansion of the exponents there to end up with the first line? Probably, you should delete your answer.

Comment: @Lipschitz: So you want to prove the 1st line? I misunderstood your question. You are given the standard Holder's ineq. and want to prove this version. Is that correct?

Comment: this is correct. and the expansion in the second line is supposed to be useful somehow.

Comment: @Lipschitz: I posted a link where your proof is done just the way you want it. This is actually called the Young's inequality for convolutions (You probably knew it before anyway).